# Showing $E[X_n]\to E[X]$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-integrability

> Given $\{X_n\}_n$ are uniformly integrable non-negative random variables with $X_n\rightarrow X$ almost surely then show that $E[X_n]\to E[X]$

Uniform integrability implies $\sup_nE|X_n|<\infty$ then does the rest not follow from the generalized dominated convergence, where do I need non-negativity ?

Comment: What do you think the generalised DCT says? It is not true that $\sup_n E|X_n| < \infty$ and $X_n \to X$ a.e. implies that $E[X_n] \to E[X]$ (even for non-negative random variables). For example, consider $X_n = n 1_{[0,\frac1n]}$ as a random variable on the probability space $([0,1], B([0,1]), \lambda)$ for $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @RhysSteele Is that uniformly integrable ?

Comment: No, that's the point. As I understand it, the argument you've written only uses uniform integrability to conclude that $\sup_nE[X_n]<\infty$ and so if correct should work for any sequence $X_n$ satisfying that weaker condition. This is an example where the weaker condition is true but the conclusion is false so the argument must fail unless there is a hidden use of the uniform integrability hypothesis elsewhere. The only place that could be is in the statement of whatever you're calling the generalised DCT which is why I asked you to clarify.

Comment: @RhysSteele The argument is from here on page 9 lemma 4.21, http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~neldredge/6710/6710-lecture-notes.pdf   and the dominated convergence is http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-generalized-lebesgue-dominated-convergence-theorem

Comment: Rhys Steele was not arguing with the implication (UI) $\Rightarrow \sup_n E|X_n| < \infty$. They were pointing out that you are not using the full strength of uniform integrability in your argument, which you need. You will need to split $E|X_n - X|$ in two: the event $\{|X_n - X| < \epsilon\}$ and the event $\{|X_n-X| \geq \epsilon\}$. The second event is small due to UI.

Comment: You can't use the version of the dominated convergence given at that link (or indeed any version) in the way you do since you don't check the hypotheses. Notice that in the theorem it is assumed you can find $g_n$ dominating $f_n$ such that $g_n \to g$ pointwise and $\lim_n E[g_n] = E[g]$. Here you have no good candidate for $g_n$. Indeed the only thing you've introduced is $X_n$ itself and if you take that as $g_n$ then to prove the hypothesis you need to know that $E[X_n] \to E[X]$ before you start!